# Looking for information on vintage E-CO BMX

Tags: vintage, bmx

Does anyone have more information on E-CO BMX bikes? I don't even know their nationality. I know of two models, the Ultra and the Mega Performer. Any help or material will be great. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! What kind of information are you looking for in addition to where they are made?

Comment: In the catalog what does it say above "HIGH PERFORMANCE"?

Answer (score 0):

Second photo shows a detangler, so its intended to do bar spins, implying the bike is set up for tricks and not BMX.

The first box-photo appears to show pegs on the read axle but not the front.

White tyres are known for getting dirty quickly and also not coping very well with UV over time compared to black tyres.

The advert copy screams `90's so I think you're looking at an early 90s kid's BMX.  This sort of bike is sold to parents and the child might ride it a little or a lot.  It doesn't appear to be a racing BMX.

Another observation is the phone number listed is 7 digits.  Presuming its a US number, that implies its a "local" number whereever that advert is from.  If you find what city/state it is from that may give more locality information.